# WebGL: Scaling affects normal matrix?

Tags: webgl

I'm playing around with WebGL, I scipted a simple flat-shaded cube. 
I got a shader which takes projection matrix, view model matrix and a normal matrix, nothing fancy:

```
(...)
void main(void) {
    gl_Position = uPMatrix * uMVMatrix * vec4(aVertexPosition, 1.0);
    vTextureCoord = aTextureCoord;

    vec3 transformedNormal = uNMatrix * aVertexNormal;
    float directionalLightWeighting = max(dot(transformedNormal, uLightingDirection), 0.0);
    vLightWeighting = uAmbientColor + uDirectionalColor * directionalLightWeighting;
}
```

Everything is fine, the flat shading looks good, but as soon as I resize the cube (noted as mat4.scale below), the shading does not affect the scene anymore. If I scale down the computed normal matrix by the reverse factor, it works again.

The code follows the following schema (drawing pseudo routine):

```
projection = mat4.ortho

// set up general camera view 
view = mat4.lookAt

// set up cube position / scaling / rotation on view matrix
mat4.translate(view)
mat4.scale(view) // remove for nice shading ..
mat4.rotate(view)

// normalFromMat4 returns upper-left 3x3 inverse transpose
normal = mat4.normalFromMat4 ( view )

pass projection, view, normal to shader
gl.drawElements
```

I am using gl-matrix as math library.
Any ideas where my mistake lies?

Comment: are normalizing your normals in your shaders? If not they'll get scaled.

Comment: That's it - I've overseen that. Thank you ;)